# Hide empty cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a searchable tableview, but would like to only display the number of cells that are returned once a user starts a search. For instance, if a user types in a charecter and there is only one cell that matches the search, the remaining cells the remaining cells of the table are empty. I was wondering if there is a way to hide those empty cells. I was also wondering if there is a way to hide the table view if a person's search does not match any data (by default, it displays a table of empty cells saying "No Results").

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` in your data source to return the number of search results instead of the total number of items.  Then populate those cells with the search results instead of with the rest of the data.

Answer (score 61):

Set the `tableFooterView` to some dummy view (`[[UIView new] autorelease]` will work fine).  This prompts the `UITableView` to show the footer (which will have zero size) in place of the empty 'cells'.

Comment: @codejunkie - I haven't tried; should work fine but you dont need the autorelease.

Comment: @TomSwift same code complains when doing that i guess need to look up more what to replace in iOS5 for autorelease

Comment: @codejunkie - if you're using ARC you dont autorelease.  Just use [UIView new]

Comment: @TomSwift ok i see it hidden cells which were created by default by view "but" it doesnt hide my main problem as i have some empty cell which are selectable but have no-content how can i hide them?  i have asked a new question for this.

Comment: Question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859427/check-for-cell-content-and-hide-as-needed-obj-c

Comment: Although this answer is good. NEVER call ``new`` --- always ``alloc`` ``init``

Comment: @Daniel - I prefer 'new' for parameterless initialization.  There's no reason not to use it IMO.

Comment: @Daniel `+new` is just a convenience method - there's nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: Works great!  Tested iOS 6 & ARC

Answer (score 23):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
 *// self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];*   
  *//Since memory management is controlled by ARC now, so ignore autorelease*
  self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init] ;
}
```

Comment: self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] init]; worked but I got an error with autorelease (autorelease is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode)

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope its more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use this..

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

Answer (score 0):

For swift 2.x xCode 7 :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("∙ \(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType))")
        ...
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
       if (([array count]*65) > [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 66)
        {
          Table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 66, self.view.frame.size.width, [array count]*65)); 
        }else
       {
         Table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 66, self.view.frame.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 66);
        }
        return [array count];
}
```

here 65 is the height of the cell and 66 is the height of the navigation bar in UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding an empty cells in Swift

**Swift 3 Edition**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
}
```

**Swift 2 Edition**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```