# Custom Bottom Border not appearing on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I added a bottom border to a uitableviewcell programmatically ([iPhone - Create custom UITableViewCell top and bottom borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980960/iphone-create-custom-uitableviewcell-top-and-bottom-borders)):

```
UIView *bottomLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 1)];
bottomLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:bottomLineView];
```

It's not displaying on an ipad unless you highlight it.  All the other cells below and above it have the background color set to **clear**..  It displays fine on the iPhone

Answer (score 0):

Move the line one pixel up. Right now it's outside of the frame, getting overlayed by the next cell.

```
UIView *bottomLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                               cell.bounds.size.height - 1, 
                               self.view.bounds.size.width, 
                               1)];
```

Comment: If it's out of the frame, then how is it displaying on the iPhone?