# Hide Null UItableView Cells/Rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I currently have a uitableview in place.

The data is obtained from an sqlite file.

Each column of the sqlite file will represent a list of: labels, images etc

The code i am using to get rows is

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  AppDelegate* appdelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  return [appdelegate.arrayDatabase count];

}
```

The code to populate the cells

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"simpleTableIdentifier";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  if (cell == Nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  }

  AppDelegate * appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  ShowsList *sShows = [appdelegate.arrayDatabase objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = [sShows strName ];
}
```

The problem i am having:

I want to use the labels column to populate the cell text of ViewController1.tableview but it is returning the null rows and displaying empty rows/cells in the view.

However I want to hide the rows by either counting the null cells and applying the count to the numberOfRowsInSection: method or by simply hiding empty cells.

[Hide empty cells in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248636/hide-empty-cells-in-uitableview) & [How to hide a section in UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061208/how-to-hide-a-section-in-uitableview) looks like something similar but didn't resolve my issue.

Could somebody please point me down the correct path or provide the answer :)

Thanks so much

Thomas

Comment: Did you set the delegate of tableView as self??

Comment: what are getting in appdelegate.arrayDatabase? did you get something?

Comment: Are you getting empty string as @"" or what, in your model/array ?

Comment: @sudha If i do NSLog(@"%d",[appdelegate.arrayDatabase count]); is returns 30. Instead i want to count only column 1 in the database. This i think would resolve the problem. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just implement a reloadTableData method like that

```
- (void)reloadTableData
{
// do a reload maybe from db and get yourobjects eg dbItems
// _tableItems = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (ShowsList *list in dbItems) {
        if ([list strName].length) {
            [_tableItems addObject:list];
        } 
    } 
}
```

then just use _tableItems array to populate your tableview

use [self reloadTableData] instead [self.tableview reloadData]

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  return _tableItems.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"simpleTableIdentifier";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  if (cell == Nil)
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  }

  ShowsList *sShows = [_tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = [sShows strName ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    
    
    return [[UIView alloc]init];
    
}
```

OR

There is alternate solution

you can set height of UITableView in `numberOfRowsInSection` function, having height as [array count]*(cell height)

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But it dosnt seem to solve to problem. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a mutable copy of your data object. Iterate to it first. Remove null/blank entries. Now use this modified collection for tableViewDelegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting @"" in the model from which you are populating the UITableView.

You can remove that blank like this:

[_arrays removeObjectIdenticalTo:@""];

And use this filtered array as your model to populate the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad set the table footer as:

```
[yourTableView.tableFooterView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, yourTableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
```

The footer is not used. But making its frame to sizeZero might crash the application, so use footer with height 1.
This worked for me.
Hope it helps.